# Can you direct Availability Groups to fail over to a particular node?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

Can you direct Availability Groups to fail over to a specific node in the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) with SQL Server does have the option to failover to a particular node and Availability Groups seem to build on WSFC.

Taken form the MSDN:

> `Preferred owner` A node on which a resource group prefers to run.
>   Each resource group is associated with a list of preferred owners
>   sorted in order of preference. During automatic failover, the resource
>   group is moved to the next preferred node in the preferred owner list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270278.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For alwayson availability groups, you can't do that.
After a failover SQL server will revert these settings to the current primary node.
So it won't work.